# How to limit ElasticSearch document access based on external users and groups?

Tags: elasticsearch

Each document in our index should only be accessible to specific (end) users. ACLs for each documents can be either user-based or group-based. We already have a (DynamoDB) database of users, groups, and the documents they have access to (i.e. the documents we feed to ElasticSearch).

What's the right way to enforce the document permissions in ElasticSearch, based on our existing user and group database?

Comment: Could you expand your question a bit in terms of who is going to be doing authentication. For example, do you need to allow these users to login via Kibana?  Will elasticsearch need to do authentication or these users will be already authenticated else where you just want to enforce proper permissions?

Comment: We store our users, their permissions, and the documents we want to index in our own database and thus don't rely on any 3rd party system for login. At the point we make the search query the current user has been authenticated and we know their user ID and group memberships. So we only want to enforce the permissions in the index somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do that would be to let elasticsearch handle checks. You can do it yourself by adding a filter on a top of each of your query, but it is tricky and if your users have some control over how the queries are generated there are ways to go around such filter.

So, to do it right, the ACLs should be indexed with your documents, and updated every time a document is changed. In this case you can access rules can be formulated as [templated role queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/field-and-document-access-control.html#templating-role-query). The groups and users can be either synced with Elasticsearch's native realm using security API or better yet by writing and deploying a [custom realm plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/custom-realms.html).

Comment: Are there benefits to using "templated role queries" to simply adding a field (called "acls" lets say) and add some keyword terms to represent the doc ACLs (e.g. "user:<user_id>") and then add a "filter" clause to the query containing the same (i.e. the current user's ID and any group IDs)?

Comment: It depends on how tightly you control the queries and how confident you are that developers working on this a few years from now will remember to apply it to all queries correctly :) There are several ways to go around the filter clause. To give you an example, the global aggregations will ignore any filters you add to the query but will obey the templated role queries and other security rules.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to flatten (Denormalize) those data inside the Elastic search document and perform your security checks based on query you would perform against Elasticsearch.

Denormalization is a key to Elasticsearch efficiency but the drawback will be you need to update all the documents when there is a change in the `user accesses` or the `user groups`.